# How to Pass object into filters method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to pass the object into filter and want to change the object attributes using after_filter on create action .
Simply i have Product model having attributes say name,title,price.Once product has been added i want to set change the price using after_filter so how can i pass the created @product object into filter method and change the price .

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  after_action  :change_price, only: [:create]    //what should be here..?


  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /products/new
  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

..
//rest of code
..
  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name, :category_id)
    end

    def change_name  
                                        //what should be here..? no condition say i want to change every price to 10$
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Model callback `after_create` to achieve this

Comment: I don't think that this is the purpose of the filters to change the state of an object.

Comment: I know that..i just want to know how can we pass object into filter method ..this is an example i am using here to know that..

Comment: In your example @product will be available in the after_filter since it was assigned in the create method

Answer (score 0):

The instance variable is instantly available in after filter, no action required. Because every public action created a controller instance.

But DON'T do that. Make everything you manipulated explicitly within the action. Filters are for more generic things.